# my drag & drop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want move my #timebase1 div into draghere div. now its move only the start of the div, i want to drop it in anywhere inside the dragehere div.

```js
 function funct(e) {

            var id = e.id;
            mouseXY(id);
        }

        function mouseXY(id) {

            //alert(id);
            var x = event.pageX,
              y = event.pageY
            $('#' + id).css({
                top: y,
                left: x + ''
            });
        }
```

```css
.activelevel1 {
    background-color: #EA623E;
}
.timescalebase {
    margin-top: 13px;
    height: 7px;
    position: relative;
    width:0px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="draghere"style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;">
                <div id="timebase1"draggable="true"class="timescalebase activelevel1" ondrag=funct(this)>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: If you could use jQuery plugin's try [**droppable**](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [**draggable**](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: why doesnt your html have spaces in it? is it that way only?

Answer (score 0):

You must allowdrop on your target div like this :

```js
function funct(e) {

  var id = e.id;
  mouseXY(id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function mouseXY(id) {
  var x = event.pageX,
    y = event.pageY
  $('#' + id).css({
    left: x
  });
}
```

```css
.activelevel1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.timescalebase {
  margin-top: 13px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
}
#draghere {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draghere" style="width:100%;margin-top:25px;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="timebase1" draggable="true" class="timescalebase activelevel1" ondrag="javascript:funct(this)">

  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

One example with jquery-ui :

https://jsfiddle.net/2gaq2r15/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#timebase1").draggable({
    containment: "#draghere",
    axis: "x"
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/5703316/quentin-roger.but its not working in google chrome

Comment: What is not working ? I did a fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/z2jLk5d7/. Do you want to drag the little red div on the blue line ?

Comment: yes sir its works in IE .but in chrome ,when drop the div its place to start of the draghere div (means left=0px)